# Box model issue

Tags: css

I was just play around with an layout and I'm having a problem.

My header element is pushed right to the top of the container

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CslkH

I'm missing something but I cant think what!

I have even set a margin-top and it's still push to the top of the container?

Please help guy's

Answer (score 1):

Your `.header` has a `margin-top: 25px` which, due to margin collapse, causes the `.container` to also move down.

Instead of that `top-margin`, use a `padding-top` on the `.container`.

Here's your updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbvFI

Comment: Guys thank you so much I really appreciate all the advise. It's best to make the errors now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `#container` div:

```
#container {
    background-color: #93C;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CfVAM/)**

Your floats are causing this and setting the overflow restores the block formatting context.

Comment: Floats don't destroy a block formatting context - there just wasn't one within `#container` to begin with.

Comment: @BoltClock - I meant that the floats create their own block formatting context and by adding overflow:auto to the container div the expected behavior is restored.

Comment: Guys thank you so much I really appreciate all the advise. It's best to make the errors now.